# update a column in clob(json)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have a table STUDENT and,
i have a clob field in the the database which contains data in json format ..like 
"id":["139262"],"name":["sam"] .
now the thing is that.. i want to update a key in this clob ..like "id"..based on some condition.
how can i do this using an sql/oracle query 
thanks in advance

Comment: split the column value with `:` and then update the values

Comment: @avi, are you saying that you need to update the `name` field based on a given value of `id`? You might be able to do that with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` but it definitely won't be an efficient way of handling it. It's probably not a good idea to store JSON data in the database at all if it needs to be updated via SQL.

Comment: yeah , that's right ..and yes.. REGEXP_REPLACE()  works . yeah it's bit tricky ..but that's how it is in the database already. thanks